# What crochet stitch is similar to a garter stitch in knitting?

Tags: crocheting

I was thinking about making a scarf at some point like the scarf from the 4th Doctor in the Doctor Who series. The original scarf was knitted, which I am not capable of. I like the appearance of the garter stitch that was used and is commonly used in knitting. Single crochet is a simple enough stitch but the appearance is very different.

[image: Knitting and crochet stitches]

<sup>(Left) Garter stitch (Right) Single crochet</sup>

I understand that an exact match is not possible, but the garter stitch has those nice horizontal thin rows without the "bulk" of the crochet stitches. I don't think I can just slip stitch this, but is there some stitch or stitches that I could use that would be closer to the image on the left?

Comment: If you can learn to crochet, you can learn to knit. Just saying. :)

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I am disabled and though I can crochet fairly well, knitting is not possible. I in the same position wanted to 'garter stitch' but in crochet.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, that has the advantage of only using standard crochet hooks, would be to use Slip Stitch Crochet. From the description of the craft this sounds similar to what [Ji Ugug's answer](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/2276/44) is referring to.

While the basic SS (slip stitch) is just inserting your hook through a loop, YO (yarn over), then pull through the loop you started with - Slip Stitch crochet works by changing the loops you insert your hook through and/or how you are inserting your hook into those loops (front to back or vice versa).

[image: slip stitch crochet garter stitch]

<sup>Slip stitch garter stitch</sup>

[image: slip stitch crochet rib stitch]

<sup>Slip stitch rib stitch</sup>

By working rows of slip stitches in front loops you can get the "garter" stitch. By working in the back loops you can get a rib stitch. The ladder of course more resembles its knitting equivalent.

You can read a little more on this from as well as some other slip stitch techniques at [ayarnifiedlife](https://ayarnifiedlife.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 3):

**AFGHAN STITCH CROCHET AKA TUNISIAN CROCHET**

about.com has some instructions on this stitch. It is a very easy crochet stitch that is similar to knitting. Now, it doesn't look exactly like a garter stitch, but the mechanics can get you closer to knitting. And the garter stitch is the easiest knit stitch to learn.

The difference with this stitch is that you will need a longer crochet hook about 11 - 12 inches long, because you are loading the yarn onto the hook just like in knitting.

**NEW INFO WITH GRAPHICS**

 
[image: purl Tunisian stitch]

Basic instructions for Tunisian Crochet
[image: Tunisian stitch simple]

Alternate would be the Russian Stitch which does not need the longer hook.
[image: Russian Stitch]

Rose Stitch
[image]
 [crochet](/questions/tagged/crochet)

Comment: I know you cannot add pictures as you do not have enough rep but it would be helpful if you at least link to the about.com page so people don't have to go looking for it. Depending on the complexity of the stitch you could include some basic instructions here as well.

Comment: I think this is certainly an interesting idea but it doesn't really help Matt avoid having to learn something new. Tunisian Crochet is very different than regular crochet... seems like Matt may as well learn to knit.

Comment: BTW: when you create this stitch, it gives a good "canvas" for cross stitching a design on the blanket.

Answer (score 3):

There are two techniques that produce this effect.

**Tunisian crochet** looks similar, but only on the left side - the front will look close to weaved fabric and the item will be very thick. One more difference is that left side of tunisian has an additional, raised loop, which is recognisable to trained eyes. If your work is up to 20 stitches wide, you will likely be able to use a regular crochet hook and not buy a specialized one.
Here is a sample I made while learning the basic stitches:
[image: sample left side tunisian]

The other technique, and I suspect you will like it more, is **knooking**. Knooking uses a special hook with an eye at the end and the fabric made is exactly like knit.
I don't yet do this, so here is a sample offered by search engines (which also illustrates how it works):
[image]

Comment: Knooking is very interesting as the end result looks exactly like what I was going for... might need to drill some holes in my hooks. Both suggestions require non-standard hooks.

Answer (score 1):

At youtube there is a video showing how to do it:
https://youtu.be/cYlvv03hbaE
Foundation chain: of any amount
Row 1: 1 sc into second chain from hook, 1 sc into each chain st across, turn.
Row 2: 1 sl st into each sc across, turn.
Row 3: ch 1, 1 sc into each sl st across, turn.
The result is something that looks like it has been knitted sideways, but hey, it's done with a crocheting hook!

Answer (score 0):

There is a not very used crochet style called "camel crochet" that does look quite a bit like knitting.  Maybe that would be something that would work well for this?

Comment: Welcome to Art&Crafts.SE. This answer would be improved by a picture (or a link if you don't have the rep) and/or a synopsis of a tutorial (if its not too big.) or at least a link especially if it is a _not very used crochet style_